# How could I run a while loop to update records in my table in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, while-loop

I'm using MySQL, of course.

However, I'm unable to run any while loop in the text box in the browser to update records in a table - I'm getting an error.

```
DECLARE @count INT
SET @count = 0 
WHILE @count <2000 DO
    /* loop logic in here */
    SET @count = @count + 1;
END WHILE;
```

Is the above code wrong?

Here is the error:
[image]

> MySQL said:
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'DECLARE @count INT SET @count = 0  WHILE @count <2000 DO
>       SET @count = @co' at line 1

Comment: "I'm getting an error" - care to expand on that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with a procedure like this :

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test$$
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
 DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 0;
 WHILE count < 2000 DO
   /* statment */
   SET count = count + 1;
 END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

mysql>call test();

Hope this help you.

Comment: Instead of the /* statement */ I am updating the table; however, the table records are not being updated. Is there any reason why?

Comment: For me, the records are update could you show me what is your update query ?

Comment: I had actually edited my comment, but looks like it wasn't reflected. Your example worked; I just forgot to call the SP!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong

```
DECLARE @count INT
```

can only be used in a procedure. Try

```
Set @count = 0;
```